# GCC global variable storage

Tags: gcc, global-variables, linkage

Is it possible to force gcc to store an array in a specific segment?

I want this

```
static const Host_Vtable_Entrty Host_vtable[]=
{
{"Window_create",(Function)Window_create}
,{"Window_cropEllipse",(Function)Window_cropEllipse}
,{"Window_cropRect",(Function)Window_cropRect}
,{"Window_cropRectRound",(Function)Window_cropRectRound}
,{"Window_destroy",(Function)Window_destroy}
,{"Window_filenameGet",(Function)Window_filenameGet}
,{"Window_filenameGet",(Function)Window_messageBox}
,{"Window_move",(Function)Window_move}
,{"Window_styleSet",(Function)Window_styleSet}
};
```

To be stored in a read-only place, but it is put in the data segment:

```
    .data
.align 32
_ZL11Host_vtable:
.quad   .LC0
.quad   _Z13Window_createP6WindowP6ObjectPFyS2_PjyyEPFyS2_yPvE
.quad   .LC1
.quad   _Z18Window_cropEllipseP6Windowjdddd
.quad   .LC2
.quad   _Z15Window_cropRectP6Windowjdddd
.quad   .LC3
.quad   _Z20Window_cropRectRoundP6Windowjdddddd
.quad   .LC4
.quad   _Z14Window_destroyP6Window
.quad   .LC5
.quad   _Z18Window_filenameGetPcyPKcS1_j
.quad   .LC5
.quad   _Z17Window_messageBoxP6WindowPKcS2_j
.quad   .LC6
.quad   _Z11Window_moveP6Windowdddd
.quad   .LC7
.quad   _Z15Window_styleSetP6Windowjj
```

Do I need to write the assembly manually?

Comment: It would help if you explained *why* you want to do this.

Comment: To make the program SIGSEGV if these function pointers are overwritten.

Comment: If it's read-only space, how will it be relocated? You have functions in there whose address is not known at the time the segment is created.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So these need to be changed at runtime? I see that the C++ compiler actually puts its vtable in the data section and also makes the section writable.

Comment: It needs to be changed at link time. Generally, to support run-time linking, it's treated as if it had to be writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search the GCC documentation for GCC-specific extensions to the language, you will stumble upon a document describing [variable attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes). Here you will find one attribute called `segment` with examples on how to use it.